# Client based Winsock application C++

Tags: c++, sockets

I want to make a game server/room. I tried to search it up, but it always needs a physical server room to run. Is there a way and how to make a game room by hosting it on the client's device and people can join and play?

--My own theory--

1. When the player presses "Host", create a server on their device.
2. People can enter the game code (an encoded device's public IP address) to join the room
3. Shut down server & disconnect all client when the host exit the game.
4. Player can press "Join" and enter a game code (mentioned above) to join a server.

--Problems--

1. The internet says that IP address is not the only thing needed. What more do I need?
2. When I try to connect with the public IP address, it blocks the connection (tested with a chat application I created, it can only connect with local IP such as 192.168.0.1 and not public IP like 222.133.114.88). How to make them allow my connections?

Thank you!

Comment: The usual problem with hosting the server on the client is in the modern Internet, most peoples' computers are located behind firewalls and/or NAT routers, and thus can't (easily) accept incoming connections.  If you want to locate a server there, you need to either have the user open a hole in the firewall (which most people aren't willing or able to do) or use TCP or UDP hole-punching techniques (which you can look into, but they aren't easy to implement, and they also require a public server to implement)

Comment: I don't have money for a public server, what should I do?

Comment: Maybe work on local-LAN gaming scenarios for now, and leave the across-the-Internet-gameplay use case for later (when your game is further developed and you can decide whether it's worth putting money down on server time... btw you don't have to purchase a server machine, you can open an account on AWS and rent time on a virtual server machine instead)

Comment: So, you HAVE TO get a server room, you can't play globally without a server room, right?

Comment: If there's another way to do it, I don't know what it is.  Piggyback on someone else's servers, perhaps?

Comment: I get it. What if I use P2P

Comment: P2P just means that the client computers are communicating directly with each other (rather than indirectly through a server).  Which means you'd have to make that communication happen somehow; and then you're back to the same everybody-is-firewalled problem again.

Comment: What I'm thinking is when the player enters the code, open a port on their firewall (idk how, show me) and they connect to the server with that port opened when they host. Is that it?

Comment: I googled "how to programatically open ports on firewall appliances" and this came up:  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/787082/how-to-programmatically-open-ports-on-firewall-appliances

Comment: The bind() function of winsock binds the socket with the selected port or leave port parameter as 0 to let the system choose. Essentially opening the port to accept incoming connection. Is this right or it just bind and not open?

Comment: Bind() tells windows to accept incoming connections on the port, but if the firewall is blocking the port, the packets won’t get to windows in the first place.

Comment: Opening the port on the firewall? Is that dangerous. Also, I found something call port forwarding, on the wiki says Port forwarding allows remote computers (for example, computers on the Internet) to connect to a specific computer or service within a private local-area network (LAN).

Comment: Yes, it's dangerous.  Once a port is open in the firewall, malicious actors can send packets through to that port.  Port forwarding is the same thing as opening a port.

Comment: So how do online games make it secure, isn't every time you play for example Roblox, COD, Fortnite or anything is a perfect time for attackers?

Comment: Roblox uses a public server machine, so it doesn't require opening ports in the user's firewall.

Comment: What is a public server machine and can I use it in this case?

Comment: A computer located on (and accessible to) the open internet (i.e. not hidden behind any firewall)

Comment: I mean the connection from the Roblox server to the client (behind NAT/Firewall)

Comment: The client connects to the Roblox server, not the other way around.  Firewalls allow outgoing connections to the Internet; they only block incoming connections from the Internet.

Comment: So how do Roblox send data such as player position update in a FPS game?

Comment: Either over the TCP connection that was initiated by the client, or via TCP or UDP (after using hole-punching techniques to allow that traffic through the client's firewall)

Comment: I found something. Take a look at pwnat here: https://github.com/samyk/pwnat. Look at "How Does It Works".